# How to access webcam with SWT

Tags: java, swt, webcam, jmf

I am going to access webcam in SWT, but in Java it needs to use JMF to play video, music or open webcame, but these are addable in swing component, is there any way to play video with SWT without JMF? Or open webcam in SWT without or with JMF? If there is better way to access webcam than JMF, then suggest me about that technology.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option is to embed Swing components in SWT, using [`SWT_AWT` bridge](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html). When I needed to play video (not specifically from a webcam, but it shouldn't matter) in SWT I used [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index) and converted the images it produced to SWT format, but it's currently not being 
developed further.